# Making python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I am reading the following tutorial about making a python package.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package

I prepared everything like described on this page and the installation mentioned in the end works.

But what is very confusing, when renaming the folder from mypackage to abc and also changing the lines containing mypackage in setup.py to abc. I get the following error when i try to install with pip3 install abc

> Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/.../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/io.py", line 72, in 
> AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'ABCMeta'
> Aborted (core dumped)

And when changing the name to powerspectrum I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement powerspectrum (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for powerspectrum.

But if I use as package name for example, powerspec everything works again like described in the tutorial. But somehow I am missing something. Are there protected names or are there rules how I have to choose package names? Or what else is the error I get related to?

Comment: "Are there protected names" Well, there are names that are already in use. `abc` is part of the standard library. I agree that there should be something in the Python packaging toolchain (`pip` etc.) to detect this problem and give you a more informative error message, but apparently there isn't.

Comment: Actually, I guess the problem occurs because you've managed to replace the standard library module, which causes problems for other parts of the standard library that depend on it. Uh... I hope you used a venv....

Comment: @Karl Yes I used a venv. But nothing was replaced. The installation just terminated.

Comment: Is the error that I get related to the powerspectrum name also because of an existing package or what is the problem there?

Comment: I suggest you start over in a new venv and ask a new question if the problem is still there, and give more information about what you're doing and at what point the problem occurs. Linking to an off-site tutorial helps a bit, but we need to have actual steps to reproduce in the question itself. Links rot.

Comment: The problem is still there. Like already mentioned, the environment was not damaged. But also a new environment gives the same error for the powerspectrum name

Answer (score 1):

`abc` is a module [defined by Python itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) (stands for abstract base class). `ABCMeta` is part of this module. You apparently cannot use this already defined name as your package name.